# JavaScript:Trying to get width of characters and compare

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare the width of characters in an object array in javascript. I want to create a new array with just the max-width after comparing the objects against one another. My Array looks something like this. So for example Commissions is $0.00, however the commission for next object may $200.12 (which is larger than first object by length), therefore I want to store the width of that in my new array (commission is just an example, i am trying to achieve it for all the fields)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I am kind of confused on how I can approach this. I started by creating a function called the GetWidth and return the first object in the array, now I am kind of confused on how to get the width of the character then move on to next one. Any ideas would help. Thanks

```
private GetWidth() {

    var check = this.data;
    var result = [];

   for (var i = 0; i <= check.length; i++) {
        result = check[i];

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "width" of an object? Do you just want to save the biggest `commission` property from an array of objects?

Comment: So you have a set of elements in an array and you want to get the maximum width of those elements?

Comment: Biggest commision property by length (# of characters)

Comment: Yes Ram, i want the save maximum width of those elements in length in a new array which i will use later to populate my column width.

Comment: why not compare integers rather than length?

Comment: Yes integer would work too.

Comment: will there always only be two objects to compare, or are there more?

Comment: this particular data set has only two objects however I plan on using the function for another data set as well which has more than 2 objects

Comment: so, in the case of three objects, you want the result to be the object with the biggest commission correct?

Comment: yes that is correct, however i am going to use the length to set my column size that is why i was looking for length

Comment: column size? for database storage you mean?

Comment: no to populate a grid on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the character to a span in the DOM and check the `offsetWidth` of that span. You can't get character widths natively.

```
function widthOf(char) {
  var span = document.getElement('span');

  document.body.appendChild(span);

  var width = span.offsetWidth;

  document.body.removeChild(span);

  return width;
}
```

This will also depend on char size and font-weight of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this: (check out the comments, it explains what each part does)

```
function getTopCommission() {
    var check = this.data;

    // changes Commissions from STRING to NUMBER
    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        check[i].Commissions = parseFloat(check[i].Commissions.replace(/\$/g, ''));
    }

    //sorts objects from highest to smallest
    var res = check.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.Commissions < b.Commissions
    });

    //gets size of object
    var size = 0;
    for (key in res[0]) {
        if (res[0].hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }

    //sets results
    var final = {
        obj: res[0],
        length: size
    };

    console.log(final);
}
```